# Access to Media Library

Tags: loop, media, media-library

Im trying to find a way to pull random images from either a post or wordpress's built in image library. Im not sure how to query image uris from a post or the media library - is there a tag or method that I can adopt?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you might want to check out: [get_attached_media()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) and [wp_get_attachment_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url).